# Colorear tablero de ajedrez en C

Tags: array, c, matrices

Realicé este código ahora me gustaría colorear el tablero y las fichas por separado.

He visto que se suele usar el `system("");` pero esto hace que cambie el color de la consola únicamente o el de las letras.

Hay alguna forma de poder colorear solo los cuadros del tablero?

Que debo editar del código para poder colorear el texto y los cuadros por separado.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void tablero(char [][8]);
void mostrar_tablero(char [][8] );//funcion que muestra el array

int main(){
        
    char a[8][8];

        system("cls");          
        tablero(a);
        mostrar_tablero(a);
    
}

void tablero(char a[][8]){
    
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
                
            if((i==0 && j==0) || (i==0 && j==7) || (i==7 && j==0) || (i==7 && j==7))    
            a[i][j] = 'T';
            
            else if((i==0 && j==1) || (i==0 && j==6) || (i==7 && j==1) || (i==7 && j==6))   
            a[i][j] = 'C';
            
            else if((i==0 && j==2) || (i==0 && j==5) || (i==7 && j==2) || (i==7 && j==5))   
            a[i][j] = 'A';
            
            else if((i==0 && j==3) || (i==7 && j==3))   
            a[i][j] = 'R';
            
            else if((i==0 && j==4) || (i==7 && j==4))   
            a[i][j] = 'M';
            
            else if((i==1 && (j>=0 || j<=7) || (i==6 && (j>=0 || j<=7))))
            a[i][j] = 'P';
            
            else a[i][j]='\0';  
        }
        
    }
    
}

void mostrar_tablero(char a[8][8]){
    
    int i,j;
    char l={'a'};
    
    printf("\t\t\t\t   TABLERO DE AJEDREZ");
    
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t    ");
        
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        
        printf(" %c   ",l);
        l++;
    }   
        
    printf("\n\n");
        
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        
        printf("\t\t\t%d   ",i+1);
        
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            
            printf("[%c]  ",a[i][j]);
            
        }
        
        printf("\n\n");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Todo el texto basura sobra. Si te pide más texto, de pronto es porque la pregunta es muy escueta. Por ejemplo: por qué dices que todo ese código no logra eso? Qué salida da? La idea no es hacer un code review sino responderte una pregunta. Cuál es la pregunta sobre ese código?

Comment: Haciendo `printf` estás imprimiendo por consola, y ahí no se puede cambiar el color del texto ni el fondo.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c), @TomuRain, sí, sí es posible hacerlo

Comment: Como una nota al comentario de @EduardoJiménez, si quieres usar los escape codes en la terminal de Windows (Por lo que comentaste sobre el color son `system`, y porque tienes `conio.h`, creo que es el sistema que usas), tienes que habilitarlo [de esta manera](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#samples) .